# How make dropdown list like "youtube addto favorites"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to make list like www.youtube.com "add to". How I can do this. It can be possible in asp.net.[image]

I am attaching snapshot that i want to use in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button, and a hidden div positioned juse below it. On button click, populate and reveal the div if it's hidden, or hide it if it is not. It does not really have much to do with ASP.NET, rather JavaScript.

Comment: It's a nontrivial amount of code. Try http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-drop-down-menus/ for ready-made solutions.